NodeJS child_processes how to sync AbortController between children
I want to spawn 2 children that perform their own requests through the .download_sections.sh script. If one of them fails, I want to be able to abort the other child as well. This is what I came up with, but for some reason it doesn't work and the other child keeps running.
Example: I introduced a subtle error in the youtube link for the audio, and the utility that gets the video fails with the following error:
"Error: Subprocess exited with code 1" and the abort is triggered, however, the other child keeps performing work.
export const handler = async () => {
  const sections = "*0:00:00-0:00:30,*0:01:00-0:01:30";
  const abortController = new AbortController();

  const fetchOriginalVideo = `./scripts/download_sections.sh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGl75kurxok ${sections} video`;
  const fetchAuxiliaryAudio = `./scripts/download_sections.sh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= ${sections} audio`;

  try {
    const [video, audio] = await Promise.all([
      runInParallel(fetchOriginalVideo, abortController),
      runInParallel(fetchAuxiliaryAudio, abortController),
    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    abortController.abort();
    console.error("Error during parallel execution:", err);
  } finally {
    console.log("Handler execution completed.");
  }
};

const runInParallel = (cmd: string, abortController: AbortController) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const [command, ...argumentList] = cmd.split(" ");
    console.log(command);
    console.log(argumentList);
    let child = spawn(command, argumentList, {
      signal: abortController.signal,
    });

    child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    child.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    child.on("close", (code) => {
      if (code === 0) resolve({});
      else {
        abortController.abort();
        reject(new Error(`Subprocess exited with code ${code}`));
      }
    });

    child.on("error", (error) => {
      abortController.abort();
      reject(error);
    });
  });


Have you tried creating AbortControler for each child process instead of sharing one instance across all processes?

and how would you communicate to the other child that there has been an error? @RickyMo

I don't see the problem with abort controller. How do you known that it keeps performing work? Did you try to call abort() manually, what did happen to child processes?
